# Запрет на открытие определенных файлов

Tags: kernel, c, ассемблер, linux

В Linux системе надо сделать перехват открытия файла. Запретить открывать определенные файлы. Желательно это сделать через модуль (SELinux не рассматривать). Попытка была сделать через перехват, функции открытия (`sys_call_table[__NR_open]`), все хорошо, работает, но только в консоли (если запрет на файл стоит, то открыть и прочитать из него не получиться). НО если открыть этот файл через графическое отоброжение (gedit, к примеру), то файл легко открывается. Также пробовал сделать через `LD_PRELOAD`, но что-то не получилось. Есть какие-нибудь идеи?

strace gedit показывает, что функция open вообще там не учавствует, а только read и write.
При попытке перехвата, read, получаю fd, связываю с именем файла, и опять же в консоли все работает, но при запуске через gedit запретного файла, вся система просто ложится. Даже логи не пишутся.
Код там:
http://pastebin.com/psK8vX41

Comment: Эээ... А зачем так сложно? Простого `chmod 0 filename` недостаточно?

Comment: ну если бы это так просто, не писал бы такой костыль

Comment: @Knee, а зачем в ядре?

[inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) из user тоже не работает?

Comment: это же уведомления только. Мне нужно перехватить. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Knee, Вы правы, ничего из inotify не выжать

       The inotify API provides no information about the user or process  that
       triggered the inotify event.  
       ...

это я ошибся.

--

Интересно, а как же gedit без open() получает дескриптор? От какого-то демона по sendmsg() что ли? Но open в нем  Вы ведь должны были увидеть...

Comment: Да вот, честно говоря, сам удивляюсь. Должен быть там open.
если записать лог (strace), то там можно увидеть open (на своем компе смотрел, arch, но там модуль не тестил). 

    asmlinkage int custom_open(const char __user *file_name, int flags,mode_t mod)
    {
       printk("hook: open(\"%s\")", file_name);
       return original_open(file_name, flags, mod);
    }
Этот код должен перехватывать все открытия файлов. Независимо кем. Системные в том числе. Почему-то он в syslog не пишет ничего.

Comment: @Knee, тут для форматирования кода в комментарии надо отделить его пустыми строками 

    от остального текста
    и добавить 4 пробела

перед каждой его строчкой.

Answer (score 1):

Вот немного устаревшие статьи Кодим в ядре [Linux`а №2](http://www.hackzona.ru/hz.php?name=News&file=article&sid=2238) [№3](http://www.hackzona.ru/hz.php?name=News&file=article&sid=2251) [№4](http://www.hackzona.ru/hz.php?name=News&file=article&sid=2259) где предлагается перехватывать вызовы VFS, может это поможет?

Ещё любопытная ссылка по [VFS](http://www.linuxrsp.ru/artic/linux_kernel_module_guide_development.html)
[image: Схема работы функции write()]